# Tool in QGIS to construct polygons based on network of lines

Tags: qgis, polygon, network

Is there a tool in QGIS similar to "[Contruct polygons](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/creating-new-features/constructing-polygons-from-the-geometry-of-other-features.htm)" in ArcGIS that creates polygons from existing lines?  This is different from convert `lines to polygons` that requires closed loops (minimum of three vertices). Instead, I am interested in creating lot polygons from lot boundaries or creating city blocks based on streets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that a new line begins and ends at each intersection, creating a topological network in which the lines are independent features that share nodes (their start- or end-points coincide), forming closed circuits.

---

Assuming that lines of the network are already cleaned (use [*v.clean*](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass77/manuals/v.clean.html) if not).

The QGIS tool to do what you want is called [*Polygonize*](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#polygonize).

The output is a vector layer with a Polygon feature for each closed circuit.

In a later step they can be combined with the [*Dissolve*](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#dissolve) tool.

Comment: Bear in mind, Polygonize requires completely closed loops and even miniscule (like a fraction of a millimeter) gaps will make the tool skip some boundaries. In [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/306575/119016), I had to extend all the lines in the layer by a small value for the angled rectangles to get polygonized correctly. Otherwise, they don't necessarily need to meet at vertices.

Comment: @GabrielC., that issue is part of the "use v.clean if not". In a topological network, two lines with a minuscule gap don't share a node and don't close a circuit. GRASS _v.clean_ tool is specifically designed to clean topological networks, and includes a method to connect lines separated by a distance threshold.

Comment: Yes, of course, but Polygonize can definitely work without having a topogical network. That was the purpose of my addition. I think I didn't make it clear enough.

Comment: @GabrielC., I had not understood your comment. Thanks for the clarification. It may be that the algorithm does not need exclusively that the lines share a node, probably if the lines simply cross is sufficient. But the recommendation to work with clean topological networks is something I can not avoid.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree! A topologically sound network makes a happy network (and a sane geomatician).

Answer (score 0):

yes,

go to processing > toolbox.

In the search bar look for 'lines to polygons'

run the algorithm...

Comment: see edited question with screenshots illustrating why that does not work. As I mentioned in my initial question, I am dealing with situations where `lines to polygons` does not work.

Comment: 1) First check the geometry for errors; 2) Put the erroneous sections in order; 3) The tool works correctly with the correct geometry ...

Comment: The tool (`lines to polygons`) works correctly with geometry with connected lines that join up in a particular order. It does not work for a topological network (for which the geometry has no errors). It is just a completely different set of lines.