# Finding centre line of irregular polygons with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon

I have a set of **irregular and curved polygons** which I would like to find the centre line of them. I've found some solutions for this problem such as Voronoi polygons but It doesn't work for me. It generates a zig-zag line with too many vertices. I used another solution creating centre lines joining the middle vertices from the short sides but it works well for straight polygons only but not for curved polygons. 
[Adding points along the centre lines with QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317678/adding-points-along-the-centre-lines-with-qgis)

Ideally, I would like a simple central line for each polygon with 2 vertices only. Either using QGIS/Graphical Modeler or Python. 
My target is adding points to the centre line every 3 metres, as you can see on the  image.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use `centroids` or `pole of inaccessibility` to create these lines?

Comment: I've tried to use 'centroids' and it generates points outside the polygon in some of them. Also I've tried the tool 'pole of inaccessibility' and  it doesn't create mid points for the longest polygons. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: обратите внимание на эти два решения, я думаю они вам должны помочь, правильно использовать геоинструменты: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/295348/120129; https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/318733/120129

Comment: @Cyril Thanks for that. I'll take a look at this solution.

Comment: @Cyril Could you explain with more detail the step 4 on your first solution, please? I don't get the same result as you show.

Comment: @Cyril Thanks. Now it's more clear. Unfortunately, I don't use PGAdmin. Is it better than using QGIS?

Comment: The thing is that someone is more comfortable to use. I’m more comfortable using PostgreSQL / PostGIS PGAdmin GUI for processing geodata, and for visualizing and symbolizing QGIS map objects ...

Comment: @Cyril Where can I find the tool 'Association by Basis' that you mention in your second solution? I can't find it in Geoprocessing where you said and I'm using version 3.4.6 LTR.

Comment: Merge by grounds ...I hope for the correct translation ...

Comment: Yes, I found it but it's Dissolve. Thanks

Comment: autotranslation is not always true, so I added a screenshot, the pictures are more understandable for all people on Earth: -) ...

Answer (score 3):

Try [Thin greyscale image to skeleton plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ThinGreyscale/):

> The Thin Greyscale plugin will thin a greyscale image to a greyscale
>   skeleton image, given a set of levels

1. Convert polygon to raster with Rasterize
2. Run Thin greyscale image to skeleton plugin
3. Convert to polyline using GRASS r.to.vect

[image]

Comment: thanks for your solution. I'll take a look at it.